# How can we use MVC grid for inputting data?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, gridview, grid, grid.mvc

I have to use grid not for displaying data, but for input data in MVC in multiple lines. Could you help me to implement MVCGrid for inputting data with out using third parties?

Comment: edited.... Please re-consider the decision to put the question on hold

Answer (score 1):

I used a third-party GridView for this purpose. See [DevExpress grid demos](https://demos.devexpress.com/MVCxGridViewDemos/Editing/EditModes) for details.